# Xcode Create a Photo Album App

Tags: xcode, photo

I'm relatively new to coding but I want to learn how to create a photo album app. I know there are many of them out there but I would like to learn the logistics behind having a photo app separate to the native app.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a general topic that has been asked before. It might get removed, just warning you.

Comment: this is not an answer, it should be a comment, just warning you

Comment: Thanks its just I've searched but no one seems to have tried creating a replica of the native app that is independent

Comment: I appreciate your concern however